# Remove query options from OData POST method

Tags: c#, .net-core, odata

I have an OData POST endpoint which return an OData `Created(entity)` result.
Is it possible to remove the queryable options, maybe using OData configuration?

It looks like as long as you return an entity, the queryable options ($select, $filter, $expand) are applied to the returned entity.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queryable options ($select, $filter, $expand) are applied to the returned entity if you

has [EnableQuery] attribute on your controller or action.

If you remove that, no query options will be applied.